# Logstash output to nginx

Tags: nginx, logstash

I have 3 node and run cluster `graylog-server`.
I use `nginx` for `load balancer` and on `nginx` open port (`12301`).
i want to send `log JSON format` from `logstash` to this `nginx` then `nginx`, load balancer and send to `graylog-servers`. Which `output plugin` should I use in `logstash`?

`logsstash` ( `input->tcp` )-( `output-> nginx` port(12301) ).

Answer (score 0):

If it's graylog that's answering, then use the gelf output.